# I got a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error on my Javascript project I got following a tutorial. How do I fix the error?

Tags: javascript, matrix, neural-network

I am following the Nature of Code tutorial by Code Train and when I tested the code I got the TypeError. It pointed to function FromArray, line 19. I am trying to follow his coding challenge on teaching the neural network xor, where he visualizes the xor problem. The code I have so far should produce a flicking black and white screen. Here is a specific error message I got:

```
at Function.fromArray (matrix.js:19)
at NeuralNetwork.train (nn.js:61)
at draw (sketch.js:44)
at e.d.redraw (p5.min.js:33)
at e.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:32)
at e.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:32)
at new e (p5.min.js:32)
at e (p5.min.js:32).
```

I tried rewatching some of the videos to see if I missed something and I even checked with his code on GitHub but I still get that error. I tried searching for what to do with TypeError but most answers I found on forums.

Please help. Also, his tutorial series is really good.

```
     //This is my code for the matrix math (Matrix.js): 
        
        // let m = new Matrix(3,2);
        
        
        class Matrix {
          constructor(rows, cols) {
            this.rows = rows;
            this.cols = cols;
            this.data = [];
        
            for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
              this.data[i] = [];
              for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                this.data[i][j] = 0;
              }
            }
          }
        
          static fromArray(arr) {
            let m = new Matrix(arr.length, 1);
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              m.data[i][0] = arr[i];
            }
            return m;
          }
        
          static subtract(a, b) {
            // Return a new Matrix a-b
            let result = new Matrix(a.rows, a.cols);
            for (let i = 0; i < result.rows; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < result.cols; j++) {
                result.data[i][j] = a.data[i][j] - b.data[i][j];
              }
            }
            return result;
          }
        
          toArray() {
            let arr = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                arr.push(this.data[i][j]);
              }
            }
            return arr;
          }
        
          randomize() {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                this.data[i][j] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
              }
            }
          }
        
          add(n) {
            if (n instanceof Matrix) {
              for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                  this.data[i][j] += n.data[i][j];
                }
              }
            } else {
              for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                  this.data[i][j] += n;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        
          static transpose(matrix) {
            let result = new Matrix(matrix.cols, matrix.rows);
            for (let i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < matrix.cols; j++) {
                result.data[j][i] = matrix.data[i][j];
              }
            }
            return result;
          }
        
          static multiply(a, b) {
            // Matrix product
            if (a.cols !== b.rows) {
              console.log('Columns of A must match rows of B.')
              return undefined;
            }
            let result = new Matrix(a.rows, b.cols);
            for (let i = 0; i < result.rows; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < result.cols; j++) {
                // Dot product of values in col
                let sum = 0;
                for (let k = 0; k < a.cols; k++) {
                  sum += a.data[i][k] * b.data[k][j];
                }
                result.data[i][j] = sum;
              }
            }
            return result;
          }
        
          multiply(n) {
            if (n instanceof Matrix) {
              // hadamard product
              for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                  this.data[i][j] *= n.data[i][j];
                }
              }
            } else {
              // Scalar product
              for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                  this.data[i][j] *= n;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        
          map(func) {
            // Apply a function to every element of matrix
            for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                let val = this.data[i][j];
                this.data[i][j] = func(val);
              }
            }
          }
        
          static map(matrix, func) {
            let result = new Matrix(matrix.rows, matrix.cols);
            // Apply a function to every element of matrix
            for (let i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < matrix.cols; j++) {
                let val = matrix.data[i][j];
                result.data[i][j] = func(val);
              }
            }
            return result;
          }
        
          print() {
            console.table(this.data);
          }
        }
        
        
        if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
          module.exports = Matrix;
        }
```

```
        //This the code that trains the neural network: 
        function sigmoid(x) {
            return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
          }
          
          function dsigmoid(y) {
            // return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x));
            return y * (1 - y);
          }
          
          
          class NeuralNetwork {
            constructor(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes) {
              this.input_nodes = input_nodes;
              this.hidden_nodes = hidden_nodes;
              this.output_nodes = output_nodes;
          
              this.weights_ih = new Matrix(this.hidden_nodes, this.input_nodes);
              this.weights_ho = new Matrix(this.output_nodes, this.hidden_nodes);
              this.weights_ih.randomize();
              this.weights_ho.randomize();
          
              this.bias_h = new Matrix(this.hidden_nodes, 1);
              this.bias_o = new Matrix(this.output_nodes, 1);
              this.bias_h.randomize();
              this.bias_o.randomize();
              this.learning_rate = 0.1;
            }
          
            feedforward(input_array) {
          
              // Generating the Hidden Outputs
              let inputs = Matrix.fromArray(input_array);
              let hidden = Matrix.multiply(this.weights_ih, inputs);
              hidden.add(this.bias_h);
              // activation function!
              hidden.map(sigmoid);
          
              // Generating the output's output!
              let output = Matrix.multiply(this.weights_ho, hidden);
              output.add(this.bias_o);
              output.map(sigmoid);
          
              // Sending back to the caller!
              return output.toArray();
            }
          
            train(input_array, target_array) {
              // Generating the Hidden Outputs
              let inputs = Matrix.fromArray(input_array);
              let hidden = Matrix.multiply(this.weights_ih, inputs);
              hidden.add(this.bias_h);
              // activation function!
              hidden.map(sigmoid);
          
              // Generating the output's output!
              let outputs = Matrix.multiply(this.weights_ho, hidden);
              outputs.add(this.bias_o);
              outputs.map(sigmoid);
          
              // Convert array to matrix object
              let targets = Matrix.fromArray(target_array);
          
              // Calculate the error
              // ERROR = TARGETS - OUTPUTS
              let output_errors = Matrix.subtract(targets, outputs);
          
              // let gradient = outputs * (1 - outputs);
              // Calculate gradient
              let gradients = Matrix.map(outputs, dsigmoid);
              gradients.multiply(output_errors);
              gradients.multiply(this.learning_rate);
          
          
              // Calculate deltas
              let hidden_T = Matrix.transpose(hidden);
              let weight_ho_deltas = Matrix.multiply(gradients, hidden_T);
          
              // Adjust the weights by deltas
              this.weights_ho.add(weight_ho_deltas);
              // Adjust the bias by its deltas (which is just the gradients)
              this.bias_o.add(gradients);
          
              // Calculate the hidden layer errors
              let who_t = Matrix.transpose(this.weights_ho);
              let hidden_errors = Matrix.multiply(who_t, output_errors);
          
              // Calculate hidden gradient
              let hidden_gradient = Matrix.map(hidden, dsigmoid);
              hidden_gradient.multiply(hidden_errors);
              hidden_gradient.multiply(this.learning_rate);
          
              // Calcuate input->hidden deltas
              let inputs_T = Matrix.transpose(inputs);
              let weight_ih_deltas = Matrix.multiply(hidden_gradient, inputs_T);
          
              this.weights_ih.add(weight_ih_deltas);
              // Adjust the bias by its deltas (which is just the gradients)
              this.bias_h.add(hidden_gradient);
          
              // outputs.print();
              // targets.print();
              // error.print();
            }
          
          }
```

```
        //And this does the sketch and outputs the results: 
        let nn;
        //Test Data
        let training_data = [
            {
                inputs: [0,1],
                targets: [1]
            },
            {
                inputs: [1,0],
                targets: [1]
            },
            {
                inputs: [0,0],
                targets: [0]
            },
        
            {
                inputs: [1,1], 
                targets: [0]
            },
        ];
        
        function setup() {
            //Test Data
            // for (let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            //     let data = random(training_data);
            //     nn.train(data.inputs, data.targets);
            // }
        
            // console.log(nn.feedforward([1,0]));
            // console.log(nn.feedforward([0,1]));
            // console.log(nn.feedforward([1,1]));
            // console.log(nn.feedforward([0,0]));
            createCanvas(400, 400);
            nn = new NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1);
        }
        
        function draw() {
        
            background(0)
        
            for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                let data = random(training_data);
                nn.train(data.inputs, data.outputs);
            }
        
            let resolution = 10;
            let cols = width / resolution;
            let rows = height / resolution;
            for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    fill(random(255));
                    rect(i*resolution,j*resolution,resolution, resolution)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: From the error and stacktrace it sounds like you pass something that is not at array to your `Matrix.fromArray` method, that is called from the `train` method.  You should add logging to the `train` method to make sure you always send an array to the `Matrix.fromArray` method. (use `console.log(input_array)` and `console.log(target_array)`).

Comment: Would you put the console.log(arr) in the fromArray function or in my sketch.js script?

Comment: I edited my comment, sorry. I'd add the console.log in the sketch script, I wasn't sure it was your script at first. You have the problematic line of code in the stacktrace (sketch.js:44 - line 44), you can add logging just before that line.

Comment: I tried it but I got input_array is not defined. It isn't one script so I think it is because of that. I also edited my question to separate each script. Thanks for you the help by the way.